# How to find duplicates records across multiple columns

Tags: sql, database, email, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-analysis

I have a contacts table that has multiple emails and phone columns. My goal is to find duplicate records by comparing these emails and phone numbers and marking duplicates in groups.

| id | email1 | email2 | email 3 | phone1 | phone 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | email1 | email2 | email3 | 123 | 321 |
| 2 | email2 | email4 | email5 | 234 | 432 |
| 3 | email6 | email7 | email8 | 234 |  |
| 4 | email9 | email10 | email11 |  |  |
| 5 | email12 | email9 |  |  |  |

In the example above, records `1` and `2` are duplicates because they are holding the same email `email2`, and records `2` and `3` are duplicates because they have the same phone `234`.
Because record `2` duplicates with both `1` and `3`, records `1`, `2`, `3` should be marked in one duplication group.

The expected output should be like this:

| dup_grpup | record_id |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| A | 3 |
| B | 4 |
| B | 5 |

I've been trying for 2 days and still haven't come up with a solution. I can do this with programing language, but I'm interested in implementing it in SQL.

Any suggestions and ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could use some window functions and an `unpivot` to accomplish something like this.  I'm using `rank()` in my example, which will give you a numeric dupe group.  I am only doing emails in this example, but you could simply do a union with the same logic for phones:

```
with x as (
    SELECT id, email1, email2, email3
    FROM (VALUES (1,'email1','email2','email3'),
                 (2,'email2','email4','email5'),
                 (3,'email6','email7','email8'),
                 (4,'email9','email11','email10') y (id,email1,email2,email3)
         )
)
SELECT id, 
--     emails, 
       RANK() OVER (ORDER BY emails) as dupe_group
FROM x
UNPIVOT(emails for email in (email1,email2,email3))
QUALIFY COUNT(DISTINCT id) OVER (PARTITION BY emails) > 1
;
```

Please note that the cte at the beginning is just creating a dataset to test with.  And I commented out emails in the output, since you don't have it in yours, but I used it to make sure my code was working.

Comment: I doubt this works as needed. If there is a 'email1' element in row with id=3 then it should fall in same group, but that will not happen here.

Comment: I think you are assuming that it should be in the same dupe group.  I actually think it should fall into a different dupe group, since it's a dupe for a different reason.  The OP doesn't specify that dupe groups should be recursively closed for any matching reason.

Comment: Perhaps the question poster can clarify on that.
I checked with changing email6 to email1 in id=3.
Got Output ```(ID,EMAILS,DUPE_GROUP) - (1,email1,1),(3,email1,1),(1,email2,5),(2,email2,5)```
Expected - both email1 and email2 should fall in same group i.e. group 1. Refer following statement in the question - "Because record 2 duplicates with both 1 and 3, records 1, 2, 3 should be marked in one duplication group."

Comment: Ah, that'd need transitive closure to accomplish.  That'd be no fun at all.  If the OP can clarify, I'd be happy to remove this answer if I incorrectly interpreted the ask.

Comment: Pankaj is correct.  record 1,2,3 should be in one group in this scenario. but your answer had provided me with some new ideas, I can use a recursive CTE based on your SQL to achieve my goal.

Comment: @MikeWalton Your answer is really helpful. you should leave the answer here to help other people. I will update the question to attach my final solution if I succeed, and you should take the credit.

Comment: @MikeWalton I finally implemented it based on your answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73049951/how-to-find-duplicates-records-across-multiple-columns/73077997#73077997

Answer (score 1):

In below query -

- First CTE `with data` - is only data.
- Second CTE `cte_1`
  combines all email and phone columns into an array.
- Third CTE
  `cte_2` is the core of the entire query. It uses function `arrays_overlap` to compare current
  record with all other records in the table using self-join.  In case
  of match it picks the least of two IDs that are matching. Column
  `child` in `cte_2` creates the pivot or starting point for different
  hierarchical groups in the data-set.
- Fourth CTE `final_cte` picks
  the minimum and creates the final hierarchical data-set which links
  each id (parent) via column chk (child) in `final_cte`.
- Lastly, hierarchial query is used to get the top root for each element.

I had to use `coalesce` as function [arrays_overlap](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/arrays_overlap.html#arrays-overlap) is NULL-safe, so it returns true when comparing NULLs, so by using `coalesce`, I ensured that null records in across rows are unique.

```
with data (id,email1,email2,email3,phone1,phone2) as (
select * from values
(1,'email1','email2','email3',123,321),
(2,'email2','email4','email5',234,432),
(3,'email6','email7','email8',234,null),
(4,'email9','email10','email11',null,null),
(5,'email12','email9',null,null,null)
), cte_1 (id,arr) as
(select id,
array_construct(
coalesce(email1, id::string),
coalesce(email2, id::string),
coalesce(email3, id::string),
coalesce(phone1, id::number),
coalesce(phone2, id::number))
from data), cte_2 as (
select c1.id id1,c2.id id2,
case when arrays_overlap(c1.arr,c2.arr) then least(c1.id,c2.id) else null end chk,
case when (id1 = chk) then null else chk end child
from cte_1 c1 left join cte_1 c2
where c1.id != c2.id ), final_cte as (
select id1, 
min(child) chk
from cte_2
group by id1
order by id1
)
select id1, connect_by_root id1 as parent from final_cte 
start with chk is null 
connect by chk = prior id1 
order by id1;
```

| ID1 | PARENT |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 4 |

If you indeed need dup_group as A,B,C then add another query at the end; something like -

```
select id1, 
chr(65+conditional_change_event(parent) 
over (order by id1)) dup_group 
from cte_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

With the help from @mike-walton and @pankaj, I achieved the goal with the following SQL:

```sql
with data as (
    SELECT user_id, email1, email2, email3
    FROM (VALUES (1,'email1','email2','email3'),
                 (2,'email2','email4','email5'),
                 (3,'email6','email7','email8'),
                 (4,'email9','email11','email10'),
                 (5,'email4','email12','email13'),
                 (6,'email14','email9','email15') y (user_id,email1,email2,email3)
         )
),
-- 1. Find duplicates
dups as (
    SELECT 
        user_id, 
        RANK() OVER (ORDER BY emails) as group_id
    FROM data
    UNPIVOT(emails for email in (email1, email2 ,email3))
    QUALIFY  COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) OVER (PARTITION BY emails) > 1
),
-- 2. Merge overlapped dup groups.
group_members as (
    select 
        group_id, array_agg(user_id) users
    from dups
    group by group_id
),
overlapped_group as (
    select 
        c1.group_id g1,
        c2.group_id g2,
        least(g1, coalesce(g2, g1)) as min_group,
        min(min_group) over (partition by g2) as merge_to
    from group_members c1
    left join 
        group_members c2 on arrays_overlap(c1.users, c2.users) 
        and g1 <> g2
), 
merge_mapping as (
    select
        distinct
        g1 as group_id,
        iff(g2 is null, g1, min(merge_to) over (partition by g1)) as merge_to
    from overlapped_group
)

select
    distinct
    user_id,
    m.merge_to as group_id
from dups 
left join merge_mapping m using(group_id) order by group_id;
```