# Identify related groups of edges in cyclic graph in SQL

Tags: sql, graph, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'd like to do the following in SQL (Snowflake dialect):

Given a group of edges containing cycles

```
FROM_NODE | TO_NODE
--------- | -------
A         | B
B         | C
C         | D
D         | C
E         | F
G         | H
H         | G
```

Identify all unique groups of related nodes

```
FROM_NODE | TO_NODE | GROUP_NAME
--------- | ------- | ----------
A         | B       | 1
B         | C       | 1
C         | D       | 1
D         | B       | 1
E         | F       | 2
G         | H       | 3
H         | G       | 3
```

The code below runs forever (because of the cycles?) (taken from here: [How to identify groups/clusters in set of arcs/edges in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45212799/how-to-identify-groups-clusters-in-set-of-arcs-edges-in-sql)):

```sql
WITH edges as (
    select * from (
        values
            ('A', 'B'),
            ('B', 'C'),
            ('C', 'D'),
            ('D', 'B'),
            ('E', 'F'),
            ('G', 'H'),
            ('H', 'G')
    ) as e (FROM_NODE, TO_NODE)
),

groups (FROM_NODE, TO_NODE, GROUP_NAME) AS (
    SELECT
        e1.FROM_NODE,
        e1.TO_NODE,
        Rank() Over (ORDER BY e1.FROM_NODE) as GROUP_NAME
    FROM edges AS e1
    UNION ALL SELECT
        e2.FROM_NODE,
        e2.TO_NODE,
        g.GROUP_NAME
       FROM edges as e2, groups as g
       WHERE g.FROM_NODE = e2.TO_NODE
)

select * from groups order by GROUP_NAME
```

Comment: Refer to response from me to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73057857/13915313)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have included row id in data-set itself - same can be generated in one of the CTEs as a pseudo-column.

**Query** -

```
with data (id,from_node,to_node) as (
        select * from values
        (1,'A','B'),
        (2,'B','C'),
        (3,'C','D'),
        (4,'D','C'),
        (5,'E','F'),
        (6,'G','H'),
        (7,'H','G')
), cte_1 (id,arr) as
        (select id,
        array_construct(
            coalesce(from_node, id::string),
            coalesce(to_node, id::string))
        from data
), cte_2 as (
        select c1.id id1,c2.id id2,
        case 
            when arrays_overlap(c1.arr,c2.arr) then 
                least(c1.id,c2.id)
            else 
                null 
            end chk,
        case 
            when (id1 = chk) then 
                null 
            else 
                chk 
            end child
        from cte_1 c1 left join cte_1 c2
        where c1.id != c2.id 
    ), grp_cte as (
            select id1, 
            min(child) chk
            from cte_2
            group by id1
            order by id1
    ), relation_cte as (
            select id1, connect_by_root id1 as parent from grp_cte 
            start with chk is null 
            connect by chk = prior id1 
            order by id1
    )
select from_node, to_node, 
dense_rank() over (order by parent) group_name 
from relation_cte, data
where data.id = relation_cte.id1;
```

Will give following as output -

| FROM_NODE | TO_NODE | GROUP_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 1 |
| B | C | 1 |
| C | D | 1 |
| D | C | 1 |
| E | F | 2 |
| G | H | 3 |
| H | G | 3 |

Here is another approach -

```
with data (id,from_node,to_node) as (
        select * from values
        (1,'A','B'),
        ... truncated for bravity
        (7,'H','G')
), cte_1 as (
        select id, from_node as node from data 
        union all
        select id, to_node from data
), cte_2 as (
        select d.id , 
        (select min(id) from cte_1 c
            where d.from_node = c.node
            or d.to_node = c.node
        ) id1,
        case when id <> id1 then id1 end chk
        from data d
), relation_cte as (
        select id, connect_by_root id as parent from cte_2 
        start with chk is null 
        connect by chk = prior id
        order by id
)
select from_node, to_node, 
dense_rank() over (order by parent) group_name 
from relation_cte, data
where data.id = relation_cte.id;
```

Adding another approach using `CONDITIONAL_CHANGE_EVENT` -

```
with data (from_node,to_node) as (
        select * from values
        ('A','B'),
        ..... truncated
        ('H','G')
), cte_1 as (
        select *,
        array_construct (from_node, to_node) arr1,
        array_construct (lead (from_node) over (order by from_node), 
                        lead (to_node) over (order by to_node)) arr2,
        arrays_overlap(arr1,arr2) ao
        from data 
)
select from_node, to_node,
conditional_change_event(ao) 
    over (order by from_node,to_node) + 1  grp
from cte_1
order by from_node,to_node
```

Comment: thanks. This does work for the small data set offered as an example, but it scales poorly given the cartesian join in `cte_2` (comparing all pairs of edges). I'm hoping to find an approach that traverses the edges or accumulates matches instead of having to brute force the comparisons.

Comment: I have added more approaches to the answer. You can see if those helps your use-case.